# TIme format validation in laravel against a particular format

Tags: php, datetime, laravel-5.3, datetime-format

I am trying to get date_format validation going on in my laravel application. Its an api and get datetime in the format

```
2015-10-09T12:36:576+01:00
```

It is supposed to be IOS 8601 format so I was checking it against the format 
 `"Y-m-d\TH:i:sO"`    by using

```
'createdAt'  => "required|date_format:Y-m-d\TH:i:sO",
```

But the validation fails. I am pretty  sure that I am wrong in the format for the date(which I got from the official php documentation meaning the format for the data is not ISO 8601). Could someone please tell me what format that date is in?

Thanks

Comment: it might be the regex, i usually have to define them outside of the validation array when they get a bit long

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question but why have you got 3 numbers for your seconds value?

Comment: @RossWilson yeah seems the format provided to be was wrong(as in the numeric values were wrong). The correct format would be 2015-10-09T12:36:57+01:00

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem just now. Checking against `"Y-m-d\TH:i:sP"` works for me.

From the [PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> **P**:    Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) with colon between hours and minutes (added in PHP 5.1.3)

Answer (score 0):

Your date format ends with +01:00. You are trying to match with type `O` which is +0100 (without the colon)

See the format specs here.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

What's kind of messed up is in laravel, it creates a date object which is able to accurately read your date, but then it tries to render it back to the format you specified (removing the `:`) and then comparing it to the original, which is obviously different:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L363

This is a problem because technically both of those formats are ISO 8601 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

in laravel 9 just use

```
'date' => ['required' , 'date'],
```

```
'date' => ['required' , 'date_format:Y/d/m'],
```

Comment: The question was about validating the date against a specific format, not whether it is present at all.

Comment: ok check this      'date' => ['required' , 'date_format:Y/d/m'],